# Using a rule to increase precision

Tags: replacement, precision-and-accuracy, rule

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I can't work out how to do it.

`Construct a rule to set x=0.32 to a precision of 20 digits.`

The rule is to be applied to a expression which takes as argument 0.32 and turn than into 0.3200.... to a precision of 20 digits.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Note that I appreciate there are ways to do it without a rule, but it must be done with a rule, so it can be applied to other expressions and functions.

Thanks you.

Comment: this almost reads like a homework question, and its not exactly clear what you are after. Do you mean you *must* start with a machine representation (no back tick)?  Can you better explain why?

Comment: Yes, I must start with a machine representation.  The purpose is to be able to input a number, such as (in this example) 0.32, and observe it's output, where the precision of the final output is limited by the precision of the input.  Hence, one could simply apply this rule to the function, without explicitly changing the function, and increase it's precision.

Comment: `N[Rationalize[.32], 20]` will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a function to solve the more general problem of converting any numeric quantity into an arbitrary precision number of a specified precision.

```
ToArbitraryPrecison[x_?NumericQ, digits_Integer?Positive] := 
  N[Rationalize[x, 10^-digits], digits]
```

Then

```
{#, Precision[#]} & /@ Thread[ToArbitraryPrecison[{3.2, Pi, 1/2 + I}, {20, 8, 4}]]
```

gives

> `{{3.2000000000000000000, 20.}, {3.1415926, 8.}, {0.5000 + 1.000 I, 4.}}`

But remember precision is not accuracy, and converting to extended precision does not increase accuracy. For example, consider

```
Pi - ToArbitraryPrecison[N[Pi], 30]
```

> `7.817936619908*10^-17`

```
Pi - ToArbitraryPrecison[Pi, 30]
```

> `0.*10^-30`

Answer (score -2):

Here is how you do it:

```
y = N[3.2, 20]
```

Comment: This does not in fact change the precision of 3.2 form MachinePrecision to 20.  It will leave it at MachinePrecision.  SetPrecision will be needed here.  Generally, `N` is not able to increase precision, only reduce it.  Example: ``Precision@N[3.2`10, 20]`` vs ``Precision@N[3.2`10, 5]``.